# MYSQL select date now-1 day with TIME and between date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I want to select all rows between current day-1 with specific time 08:00am and to date now also with specific time. This is not working for example sample line code

```
WHERE SOME_DATE_COLUMN BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) '08:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()) '08:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

I tried also DATE_FORMAT

```
WHERE SOME_DATE_COLUMN BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) '08:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE(NOW()) '08:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

If I run sql today I want to select all record between current date minus 1 day from 08:00am to current date 08:00am

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? as it is your query doesn't even execute due to invalid syntax...

Comment: If used DATE_SUB then syntax error
If used DATE_FORMAT then Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'DATE_FORMAT'

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
where 
    some_date_column >= current_date - interval 16 hour
    and some_date_column < current_date + interval 8 hour
```

`current_date` gives you the current date (without the time part). You can then add and substract the required number of hours.

Note that this query does not use `between`, but instead half-open intervals. If you want consistent, adjacent segments in time, then you want to exclude one of the bounds (by convention, generally the outer bound is excluded).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ecbc2988d8efc49ca8538a6f5a447469)**:

```
select current_date - interval 16 hour, current_date + interval 8 hour
```

```
current_date - interval 16 hour | current_date + interval 8 hour
:------------------------------ | :-----------------------------
2020-02-04 08:00:00             | 2020-02-05 08:00:00
```

Comment: it is not +8 hour

Comment: It is always exactly 08:00am

Comment: so how set current_date and constant time 08:00am
for example some_date_column >= current_date - 1day '08:00:00' and some_date_column < current_date '08:00:00'

Comment: @Kutasek: I think that this expression does what you ask for. I added a fiddle to my answer for your reference. Please incoporate my expression in your code and test the query against your data.

Comment: i can't use interval because this is live sql I need contains time between current_date -1 '08:00:00' to current_date '08:00:00'

Comment: @Kutasek: you tagged your question MySQL, so my answer is MySQL syntax. Is MySQL the database that you are using?

Comment: how can I substract to start time 07:59? select current_date - interval 16 hour - 1 MINUTE?

Comment: That would be: `current_date - interval 16 hour - interval 1 minute`